# Browserstack: Facing an issue while trying to execute multi browser parallel test in browserstack using junit5

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit5, browserstack

While trying to execute multi browser parallel test in browserstack using junit5, I am facing a issue. The tests is getting triggered and both the browsers are getting started in the browser stack. However one of the browser will get timed out with out executing the tests. I have attached a screen shot below.

I tried with the Junit 4 and it was working properly. There are slight difference in the way the parallel tests are implemented in both junit 5 and junit 4

```
public class BrowserStackJUnitTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    private Local l;
    private static JSONObject config;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(TestInfo testInfo) throws Exception {
        if (System.getProperty("config") != null) {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            config = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("src/test/resources/conf/" + System.getProperty("config")));
        }
        JSONArray allEnvs = (JSONArray) config.get("environments");

        for (int i = 0; i < allEnvs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Environments: " + allEnvs.get(i));

            Object envs = allEnvs.get(i);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            Map<String, String> envCapabilities = (Map<String, String>) envs;
            Iterator it = envCapabilities.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                capabilities.setCapability(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue().toString());
            }

            Map<String, String> commonCapabilities = (Map<String, String>) config.get("capabilities");
            it = commonCapabilities.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                if (capabilities.getCapability(pair.getKey().toString()) == null) {
                    capabilities.setCapability(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            capabilities.setCapability("name", commonCapabilities.get("name").concat("_").concat(testInfo.getDisplayName()));

            String username = System.getenv("BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME");
            if (username == null) {
                username = (String) config.get("user");
            }

            String accessKey = System.getenv("BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY");
            if (accessKey == null) {
                accessKey = (String) config.get("key");
            }

            if (capabilities.getCapability("browserstack.local") != null && capabilities.getCapability("browserstack.local") == "true") {
                l = new Local();
                Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
                options.put("key", accessKey);
                l.start(options);
            }

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://" + username + ":" + accessKey + "@" + config.get("server") + "/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        }
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (driver != null) driver.quit();
        if (l != null) l.stop();
    }

}
```

**paralle.conf.json**

```
{
  "server": "hub-cloud.browserstack.com",
  "user": "<user>",
  "key": "<key>",
  "capabilities": {
    "build": "MultiBrowserTest",
    "name": "ParallelExecute",
    "browserstack.debug": true
  },
  "environments": [
    {
      "browser": "chrome",
      "os": "Windows",
      "os_version": "10"
    },
    {
      "browser": "Firefox",
      "os": "Windows",
      "os_version": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Test**

```
@Test
    public void sampleTest1() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello World");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
    }
```

**Triggered as maven**

```
mvn clean test -P parallel
```

**In pom.xml**

```
<properties>
 <configurationParameters>
  junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true 
  junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
 </configurationParameters>
```

**Issue Occured**

The test will get triggered and will execute in parallel in browser stack, however one of the browser will get timed out with out executing the tests
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This happens when no Selenium or Appium commands are received from the test scripts for 90 seconds. I think this might help you: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/error-codes/browserstack-idle-timeout

Comment: Actually, the question was about the execution of a multi browser parallel (chrome + firefox + safari) test while using junit 5. I can execute single browser (multiple instances of chrome) parallel tests by specifying the configuration parameters in the pom, however when it comes to multi browser parallel ( chrome + firefox + safari) it did not work for me.. I also have not seen a solution for this here - https://github.com/browserstack/junit-browserstack/tree/junit5 
If I specify the browsers in an array as shown in the parallel.conf.json, how can I execute multi browser parallel tests?

Comment: I found that if I reduce the number of browsers in browserstack.json, and only execute tests in one or two browsers at a time, it reduces the chances of getting the "all parallels are currently in use" error.